# What is the best way to slice a sub-DataFrame of a Deedle DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, f#, slice, deedle

I was able to slice a sub-DataFrame of a `Deedle DataFrame` in two ways:

a) Extract the rows using `df.Rows.After` and then reconstruct using `Frame.ofRows`

b) Use `Frame.filterRows`

However, it would be much neater to just write `df.[someDate..]` but that generates an error. Please see the code below.

What is the best way to copy/update a DataFrame by slicing a contiguous subset of its rows?

```
open Deedle

let dates  = 
  [ DateTime(2013,1,1); 
    DateTime(2013,1,4); 
    DateTime(2013,1,8) ]

let values = [ 10.0; 20.0; 30.0 ]

let first = Series(dates, values)
let second = Series(dates, List.map (fun x -> x * 5.0) values) 

let df1 = Frame(["first"; "second"], [first; second])

let someDate = DateTime(2013,1,5)

let df2 = Frame.ofRows (df1.Rows.After someDate)
// Ok, a one-row DataFrame

let f firstDate (dt: DateTime) (x: ObjectSeries<string>) = (dt > firstDate)
let df3 = Frame.filterRows (f someDate) df1
// Ok, a one-row DataFrame

let df4 = df1.[someDate..]
// error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'GetSlice' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the slicing syntax on `df1.Rows` or `df1.Columns`. Even though those behave as series for most things (including the fact that you can call `After` on them), they return a new data frame when you use them via slicing.

The following should do exactly what you need:

```
let df4 = df1.Rows.[someDate..]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.